# Why sample iOS app in XCode 6 checks for nil of a non-optional variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

In "Master-Details" sample Swift app that comes with XCode 6 in `MasterViewController.swift` file they define `objects` like this:

```
var objects = NSMutableArray()
```

Then in `insertNewObject` method they check against `nil` before using it:

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    if objects == nil {
        objects = NSMutableArray()
    }
    objects.insertObject(NSDate.date(), atIndex: 0)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

If `objects` is not optional and `objects = nil` throws an error, why do they need to guard against `nil`?

Comment: I think it just bug in the template code... you should submit a bug report

Answer (score 1):

That is a bug; I find it surprising that it compiles without an error or warning. (I guess it's probably being turned into a call to isEqual:, passing nil?) Interestingly, the more idiomatic version:

```
if objects {
    objects = NSMutableArray()
}
```

Does actually fail; you get an error on the `if objects` line because you can't test an NSMutableArray for boolean-ness.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to guard against `nil`. That's the entire point of optionals (or non-optionals). Also, in Swift, when you *are* testing for `nil`, if the variable is an optional (which is the only time it could be `nil` anyhow), you can just say:

```
if optionalVar { 
    // do stuff
}
```

This is probably just translated from the Objective-C version by Xcode and isn't made "Swifty."

Another instance of this kind of thing:

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    // Custom initialization
}
```

The `// Custom initialization` should go above the `super.init()` in Swift, but this is just translated from the Objective-C version.